# Need help calling a function from another class in python

Tags: python, function, class, methods, import

I wrote a simple unit converter program. In the main() class, I have the basic program asking the user to choose which converter to use. Then I wrote a specific class for each converter. What I would like to do is to import each converter method into main. Truth be told, I'm not sure if I even need main(). Anyway, all classes work, I just don't know how to import the methods into their appropriate placeholders. I hope this makes sense.

```
print("Welcome to the Amazing Converter!\n")

def main():

    print("[1] Convert Temperature")
    print("[2] Convert Distance")
    print("[3] Convert Weight")

    again = True
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input("What would you like to convert? "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid entry.")
        
        if choice == 1:
            print("[1] Convert from Celsius to Farenheit")
            print("[2] Convert from Farenheit to Celsius")
            temp_choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

            if temp_choice == 1:
                pass
            elif choice == 2:
                pass
                    
        elif choice == 2:
            print("[1] Convert from Miles to Kilometers")
            print("[2] Convert from Kilometers to Miles")
            dist_choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

            if dist_choice == 1:
                pass            
            elif dist_choice == 2:
                pass
            
        elif choice == 3:
            print("[1] Convert from Pounds to Kilos")
            print("[2] Convert from Kilos to Pounds")
            weight_choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

            if weight_choice == 1:
                pass
            elif weight_choice == 2:
                pass   

        again = input("Would you like to Convert another unit of measurement? ")
        if again == 1:
            True
        else:
            print("Have a good day!")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()




#Convert Celsius to Farenheit
class Temperature:
    temp = 0
    def __init__(self, temp):
        self.temp = temp

    def cel_to_far(self):
        res = (self.temp * 9/5) + 32
        return res

celsius = float(input("Enter celsius value: "))  
far_temp = Temperature(celsius)
print(round(far_temp.cel_to_far()))



#Convert Farenheit to Celsius
class Temperature:
    temp = 0
    def __init__(self, temp):
        self.temp = temp

    def far_to_cel(self):
        res = (self.temp - 32) * 5/9
        return res

farenheit = float(input("Enter farenheit value: "))  
cel_temp = Temperature(farenheit)
print(round(cel_temp.far_to_cel()))


#Convert miles to kilometers
class Distance:
    dist = 0
    def __init__(self, dist):
        self.dist = dist

    def mil_to_kil(self):
        res = (self.dist * 1.609344)
        return res

miles = float(input("Enter mile value: "))
miles_dist = Distance(miles)
print(round(miles_dist.mil_to_kil()))



#Convert kilometers to miles
class Distance:
    dist = 0
    def __init__(self, dist):
        self.dist = dist

    def kil_to_mil(self):
        res = (self.dist * 0.62137)
        return res

kilometers = float(input("Enter kilometer value: "))
kilo_dist = Distance(kilometers)
print(round(kilo_dist.kil_to_mil()))


#Convert pounds to kilos
class Weight:
    def __init__(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight

    def pound_to_kilo(self):
        res = (self.weight * 0.45359237)
        return res

pounds = float(input("Enter pound value: "))
pound_weight = Weight(pounds)
print(round(pound_weight.pound_to_kilo()))


#Convert kilos to pounds
class Weight:
    def __init__(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight

    def kilo_to_pound(self):
        res = (self.weight / 0.45359237)
        return res

kilos = float(input("Enter kilo value: "))
kilo_weight = Weight(kilos)
print(round(kilo_weight.kilo_to_pound()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your created duplicated classes. so make them easier like

```
class Temperature:
    
    def cel_to_far(self, temp):
        res = (temp * 9/5) + 32
        return res

    def far_to_cel(self, temp):
        res = (temp - 32) * 5/9
        return res
```

and create object for that class, like this

```
def main():
    
    # creating object
    temperature = Temperature()
```

and calling that Temperature methods be like

```
        if choice == 1:
            print("[1] Convert from Celsius to Farenheit")
            print("[2] Convert from Farenheit to Celsius")
            temp_choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

            if temp_choice == 1:   
                celsius = float(input("Enter celsius value: "))  
                print(round(temperature.cel_to_far(celsius)))
            elif choice == 2:
                farenheit = float(input("Enter farenheit value: "))  
                print(round(temperature.far_to_cel(farenheit)))
```

Hoping, you got it.

Comment: Hey Arun_b, yeah I got it! I included both methods for each class instead of creating different classes for each method. Also, I completely forgot to close main() at the very end, which is why it wasn't working. I upvoted your answer but it doesn't show because i have less the 15 reputation points.

Comment: It's ok @RobinSage

Answer (score 1):

You already have examples below each class of how to use that class. For example, below where your `Temperature` class is defined, you have:

```
celsius = float(input("Enter celsius value: "))  
far_temp = Temperature(celsius)
print(round(far_temp.cel_to_far()))
```

What you need to do is to move those to the relevant parts of `main`, where you want to use them.  For example where you have:

```
            if temp_choice == 1:
                pass
```

you would put it (suitably indented) in place of the `pass`.

```
            if temp_choice == 1:
                celsius = float(input("Enter celsius value: "))  
                far_temp = Temperature(celsius)
                print(round(far_temp.cel_to_far()))
```

However, the other thing you need to do is to move the code which calls `main`, namely:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

to the end of the module after the other classes have been defined.

If you try it as it is at the moment, you would get a `NameError` because the other classes have not yet been defined when `main` is called.

And in fact you don't really need the

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

unless you might also import your module into another one.  If you know that you will only run it directly as a main program (`python your_module.py`) then it is sufficient just to put `main()` at the end.

Finally, it seems that your the classes for converting e.g. temperature in the two directions have the same name (both called `Temperature`).  Whilst you could rename them to avoid a name conflict, they are in fact in a suitable form for merging into a single class that has both `cel_to_far` and `far_to_cel` methods, and similarly for the other classes.

Putting this all together (and removing the bit about repeating "would you like to convert another unit?" which is out of scope for this question), the code would look like this:

```
print("Welcome to the Amazing Converter!\n")

def main():

    print("[1] Convert Temperature")
    print("[2] Convert Distance")
    print("[3] Convert Weight")

    again = True
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input("What would you like to convert? "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid entry.")
        
        if choice == 1:
            print("[1] Convert from Celsius to Farenheit")
            print("[2] Convert from Farenheit to Celsius")
            temp_choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

            if temp_choice == 1:
                celsius = float(input("Enter celsius value: "))  
                far_temp = Temperature(celsius)
                print(round(far_temp.cel_to_far()))
            elif temp_choice == 2:
                farenheit = float(input("Enter farenheit value: "))  
                cel_temp = Temperature(farenheit)
                print(round(cel_temp.far_to_cel()))
                    
        elif choice == 2:
            print("[1] Convert from Miles to Kilometers")
            print("[2] Convert from Kilometers to Miles")
            dist_choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

            if dist_choice == 1:
                miles = float(input("Enter mile value: "))
                miles_dist = Distance(miles)
                print(round(miles_dist.mil_to_kil()))

            elif dist_choice == 2:
                kilometers = float(input("Enter kilometer value: "))
                kilo_dist = Distance(kilometers)
                print(round(kilo_dist.kil_to_mil()))
            
        elif choice == 3:
            print("[1] Convert from Pounds to Kilos")
            print("[2] Convert from Kilos to Pounds")
            weight_choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

            if weight_choice == 1:
                pounds = float(input("Enter pound value: "))
                pound_weight = Weight(pounds)
                print(round(pound_weight.pound_to_kilo()))
            elif weight_choice == 2:
                kilos = float(input("Enter kilo value: "))
                kilo_weight = Weight(kilos)
                print(round(kilo_weight.kilo_to_pound()))


class Temperature:
    temp = 0
    def __init__(self, temp):
        self.temp = temp

    def cel_to_far(self):
        res = (self.temp * 9/5) + 32
        return res

    def far_to_cel(self):
        res = (self.temp - 32) * 5/9
        return res


class Distance:
    dist = 0
    def __init__(self, dist):
        self.dist = dist

    def mil_to_kil(self):
        res = (self.dist * 1.609344)
        return res

    def kil_to_mil(self):
        res = (self.dist * 0.62137)
        return res


class Weight:
    def __init__(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight

    def pound_to_kilo(self):
        res = (self.weight * 0.45359237)
        return res

    def kilo_to_pound(self):
        res = (self.weight / 0.45359237)
        return res


main()
```

Comment: Note: just seen that some of the classes have the same name.  About to deal with this... watch this space.

Comment: Alaniwi, thank you so much for the help! I had already replaced the code from the classes with the PASS in the method within main(). In fact, I had done everything you suggested (except using both methods for each class instead of using 2 classes (duh!)), but I forgot to close main() at the end. 

You mentioned not needing if __name__ == "__main__": unless I'm going to import the classes from another file. That would be nice so that I'd keep only main() in one file, and the other classes in a different file. I'd appreciate if you could show me how to do it. Again, thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: @RobinSage Well you could certainly move the classes to another file (let's say `myclasses.py`) and then all you have to do here is `from myclasses import Temperature, Distance, Weight`. If you do that - so that this module only contains the `main` function, then there is even less likelihood that you would want to import *this* module into another one, so even more reason not to bother with an `if __name__ = '__main__':` test before dong the call to `main()` at the bottom.

Comment: Alright! I'm going to try and let you know. Thank you heaps!